# Tornado performing worse with coroutines vs. without?

Tags: python, api, tornado, coroutine

My basic understanding of [coroutines in Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html) is that they are supposed to help scale an API server, especially in terms of handling concurrent requests that each take a noticeable amount of time to complete. However, in a simple load test I set up it seems that using coroutines is actually worse than using simple blocking function calls...

Below are two screenshots showing API response times using a load test concurrency level of 4 (i.e., 4 locusts or "users"). The /v1 endpoint uses simple blocking function calls, and the /v2 endpoint uses `tornado.gen.coroutine`. I expected the average response time for GET /v2/info to be significantly lower than that for GET /v1/info, but in reality the average response time is actually *higher*.

[image: GET /v1/info with 4 locusts]

[image: GET /v2/info with 4 locusts]

I feel like I'm either doing something wrong or misunderstanding a fundamental concept. Can someone tell me why my sample project is showing the numbers above? Where the coroutine-based API performs worse under concurrent load than the simple API?

Sample `tornado-loadtest` project: https://github.com/martyychang/tornado-loadtest

Answer (score 1):

Your coroutines aren't doing anything asynchronous here, so the coroutine decorator is strictly overhead. The `@coroutine` decorator is only useful when you're using `yield` to wait on other coroutines or other asynchronous operations. In this case, the slow thing you're doing is cpu-bound, so the only thing you can do to make it work better with coroutines is run it on a thread with `yield thread_pool_exector.submit(task)` (although it won't help your performance much in this case, thanks to the python GIL). Coroutines help when your program is IO-bound, or when you're keeping a connection open for external events ("real time" web apps).

Comment: Thanks for the info, Ben. So, if I understand your answer correctly: If instead of doing an in-memory calculation, the slow operation was to download a large-ish file from the internet, coroutines could then be useful?